# Javascript Assosiative Array not taking child arrays as values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, associative-array

I have this code for sortable layout management. I am trying to get the position of each div after the sortable `stop()`. Now, I was able to get everything in place within the array but the array count seems to be `0` and data is not being sent to another page.

```
    console.clear();
    finalArr = [];
    $(".rowSortable").each(function(){
      nowRow = $(this).attr('class').substr(4,5);
      finalArr[nowRow] = [];
      $(this).find(".connectedSortable").each(function(){
        nowCol = $(this).attr('class');
        nowCol = nowCol.substr(0,nowCol.indexOf(" connectedSortable"));
        finalArr[nowRow][nowCol] = [];
        $(this).find(".sortable").each(function(){
          finalArr[nowRow][nowCol].push($(this).data("field"));
        });
      });
    });
    console.log(finalArr);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(finalArr));
```

for `console.log(finalArr);`

```
home:1094
[row_1: Array(0), row_2: Array(0)]
    row_1: Array(0)
        col-md-12: Array(1)
            0: "Dog"
            length: 1
            __proto__: Array(0)
        length: 0
        __proto__: Array(0)
    row_2: Array(0)
        col-md-5: Array(3)
            0: "Cat"
            1: "Tiger"
            2: "Rat"
            length: 3
            __proto__: Array(0)
        col-md-7 left-column: Array(2)
            0: "Lion"
            1: "elephant"
            length: 2
        __proto__: Array(0)
        length: 0
    __proto__: Array(0)
    length: 0
__proto__: Array(0)
```

For `console.log(JSON.stringify(finalArr));`

```
home:1095 []
```

I also tried sending `finalArr` to a PHP page via ajax, it showed that an empty array is being posted to that page

Comment: Javascript does not have associative arrays, only indexed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're using an array as a *map*, arrays are not suitable for this. In JS, an array is a special type of object, with its own set of methods and everything assumes that it consists of integer property keys and a `length` property that specifies how many items it contains.

By setting a non-integer property of the array, its `length` property doesn't change, thus, your array ends up with `length == 0`. This is what the `JSON.stringify()` method looks at, it sees that the array's `length` is zero and that's why you get an empty array in the JSON.

- Plain objects are much better suited in this case, since their properties are arbitrary and `JSON.stringify()` handles it properly. In other words, your `finalArr` property should be a plain object, so change `finalArr = []` into `finalArr = {}`.
- On each of your *rows*, you have your *columns* which are also non-integer properties, so you also need a plain object here, so change `finalArr[nowRow] = []` into `finalArr[nowRow] = {}`.
- Then in each column you actually do use an array properly, since you're actually pushing to it, so `finalArr[nowRow][nowCol] = []` is fine as it is.

I hope this helps explain and fix your issue.

P.S. You should put `var` in front of your `finalArr` declaration. When you omit it, what you're actually doing is adding `finalArr` as a property on the `window` object. This is a bad practice and can lead to bugs that are difficult to troubleshoot. Same goes for the declarations of `nowRow` and `nowCol`.